# PHPMailler error (The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.)

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am trying to develop a form and send to email using phpmailer. sender email is Gmail. Below are my php code:

```
    <?php
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
    use PHPMailer\Exception;

    require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);                             
    try {
        //Server settings
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 4;                                
        $mail->isSMTP();                                     
        $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com'; 
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                             
        $mail->Username = 'thisismy@gmail.com';              
        $mail->Password = 'xxxxxxxx';                      
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                           
        $mail->Port = 587;



    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'Mailer');
    $mail->addAddress('receiver@gmail.com');     



    //Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  
    $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
    $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

    $mail->send();
    echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: ', $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
?>
```

I get this error **The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.**  *not using localhost

Comment: error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

Try to display the error you so can figure out what's wrong

Answer (score 0):

Read the PHPMailer readme that tells you how to load PHPMailer, and base your code on the examples provided. You are using PHPMailer 6 syntax, but trying to load it like PHPMailer 5, and the old autoloader does not exist, and trying to require it is a fatal error.

You would have found this out if you had read the most basic PHP debugging guide that would have told you to enable display of error messages, or to check your web server logs.